# Ionic input, apenas números

Tags: ionic

No Ionic como faço um campo input receber apenas números ? 
Quero um campo de idade e quero garantir que aceite apenas números, proibindo o usuário de digitar letras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar `type="number"` no `<ion-input>`.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Informe um número"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```